# How to run gradle script from gradle

Tags: gradle

How can I run another gradle script from gradle. I have multiple gradle scripts to run tests under `<root_project>/test` directory. The `<root_project>/build.gradle` is invoked with the name of the test gradle file to be run. For example

`gradle run_test -PtestFile=foobar`

This should run `<root_project>/test/foobar.gradle` (default tasks of it)

What I'm currently doing is invoking `project.exec` in the `run_test` task. This works but now I need to pass the project properties from the gradle process running run_test to the one which runs foobar.gradle

How can I do this ? Is there a more gradle-integrated way to run a gradle script from another, passing all the required info to the child gradle script ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do something similar where a "construct" task in one gradle hands off to a "perform" task in another gradle file in a dir it has created (called the artefact), and it passes through all the project properties through too.

Here's the relevant code for the handoff:

```
def gradleTask = "yourTaskToEventuallyRun"
def artefactBuild = project.tasks.create([name: "artefactBuild_$gradleTask", type: GradleBuild])
artefactBuild.buildFile = project.file("${artefactDir}/build.gradle")
artefactBuild.tasks = [gradleTask]

// inject all parameters passed to this build through to artefact build
def artefactProjectProperties = artefactBuild.startParameter.projectProperties
def currentProjectProperties = project.gradle.startParameter.projectProperties
artefactProjectProperties << currentProjectProperties
// you can add more here
// artefactProjectProperties << [someKey: someValue]

artefactBuild.execute()
```

Comment: When I try that code, with a task named `setup` in my other gradle file, I get 

`Execution failed for task ':demo'.
> Could not find method execute() for arguments [] on task ':artefactBuild_setup' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.GradleBuild.` 

and I have not been able to figure out why this code would work for you but not for me unless it is because of different versions of Gradle. I have tried and failed this code with 5.2.1 and 5.3.1.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31101231/715036) helped me achieve what I was looking to do.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to specify another gradle script, you can use:

```
gradle --build-file anotherBuild.gradle taskName
```

or

```
gradle -b anotherBuild.gradle taskName
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'd need, but unfortunately it was deprecated (the --help output says so). Does anyone know if there's a replacement? Why was it deprecated?