# calling gradle "build" task in another project

Tags: build, gradle, task

I am only a couple of days into using gradle

In my current build.gradle script I have a task which I would like to call the build task in another project (ie. defined in a different build.gradle somewhere else) after each time it is executed

My question is how do I call a task from another project?

I guess I want to do something like tasks.build.execute() but it doesn't seem to work. I tried this:

```
commandLine "${rootDir}\\gradle", 'build', 'eclipse'
```

it at least executed the build and eclipse for my current project just not the master project. Hope my question is clear

Comment: I was able to reference the task in the root project but when I do this 

rootProject.tasks.build.execute()

it doesn't seem to execute properly

Comment: What doesn't work exactly?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First read this:
http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

If you have a multi-project build
You need a root project that contains settings.gradle file with something like:

```
include 'myproject1'
include 'myproject2'
```

Then you can just make a dependency from one project to another like this:

myproject1/gradle.build

```
task someOtherTask() << {
   println 'Hello'
}
```

myproject2/gradle.build

```
task sometask(dependsOn: ':myproject1:someOtherTask') << {
  //do something here
}
```

Or if you want to call a task:

```
project(':myproject1').tasks.build.execute()
```

Notice: You have to apply java plugin to make build task available.

Answer (score 34):

Adjust the buildFile path, etc.:

```
task buildSomethingElse(type: GradleBuild) {
  buildFile = '../someOtherDirectory/build.gradle'
  tasks = ['build']
}

build.finalizedBy('buildsomethingElse')
```

Reference: Gradle organizing build logic guide, paragraph [59.5](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html).

You can apply this to another ant project as well, by adding a one line build.gradle file in your ant project that just calls ant, like so:

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
```

Comment: This is much easier than creating a multi-project build, and in some cases more appropriate.

Comment: Until I read this answer, I had thought using more than one build script in a single directory during the execution of a single `gradle` command was not possible. This seems to be a workaround for that apparent constraint.