# How to call another projects build.gradle file with command line arguments

Tags: gradle

I went through the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686698/calling-gradle-build-task-in-another-project/31101231#31101231) and successfully implemented a task which calls `build.gradle` file from another project. i.e. solution provided by @karl worked for me.

But I need something up on that.

**Can somebody help me to know how I can pass command line arguments while calling another build.gradle? Command line argument should be the variable which I have generated from my current build.gradle file.**

In my case, I am defining a buildNumber and doing something like this:

```
def buildNumber = '10.0.0.1'
def projectToBuild = 'projectName'
def projectPath = "Path_till_my_Project_Dir"
task executeSubProj << {
    def tempTask = tasks.create(name: "execute_$projectToBuild", type: GradleBuild)

    // ****** I need to pass buildNumber as command line argument in "$projectPath/$projectToBuild/build.gradle" ******

    tempTask.tasks = ['build']
    tempTask.buildFile = "$projectPath/$projectToBuild/build.gradle"
    tempTask.execute()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *never* call `execute` directly on any gradle object. The fact it's feasible doesn't mean it should be done and it's highly discouraged since you intrude internal gradle's execution graph structure.

What you need is a task of type [`GradleBuild`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/GradleBuild.html) which has [`StartParameter`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html) field that can be used to carry build options.

So:

```
task buildP2(type: GradleBuild) {
  buildFile = '../p2/build.gradle'
  startParameter.projectProperties = [lol: 'lol']
}
```

Full demo can be found [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/43672367), navigate to `p1` directory and run `gradle buildP2`.

You should modify your script in the following way:

```
def buildNumber = '10.0.0.1'
def projectToBuild = 'projectName'
def projectPath = "Path_till_my_Project_Dir"

task executeSubProj(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = "$projectPath/$projectToBuild/build.gradle"
    tasks = ['build']
    startParameter.projectProperties = [buildNumber: '10.0.0.1']
}
```

In the project that is executed use `project.findProperty('buildNumber')` to get the required value.

Comment: I am lost, How I can run other build.gradle file now? I am a beginner frnd, I am not able to understand how to execute that another build.gradle file using startParameter option. :-(

Comment: @VinayVerma, please have a look at the demo I prepared. `p1` is a project from which you run `p2` project.

Comment: Thanks a lot..!! I am happy:) The Solution you provided, it worked :-)